# Django 1.8 Domain Tutorial #3

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

*polls/templates/polls/index.html*

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The above index.html is from Tutorial #3 from Django 1.8. My question is where/how does *index.html* know which domain to use?

Answer (score 0):

The index.html file will be associated with a view and that view will be associated to a url that will be configured in the urls.py file.

When you upload your project to a server, you will then configure the servers configuration, linking your project to a domain.

Example:  myawesomedomain.com

views.py

```
def HomeView(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {context})

def ContactView(request):
        return render(request, 'contact.html', {context})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.HomeView),   # http://myawesomedomain.com
        url(r'^contact$', views.ContactView), # http://myawesomedomain.com/contact
)
```